# Gmail E-Mail forwarding add sender as CC

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-forwarding, asana

So our company is using Google Apps (or Gmail) to handle our emails. I've created an user with the address `ticket@company.com` and added an email forwarding to `x@mail.asana.com` to automatically create tickets on Asana. This works as it is supposed to. Asana automatically assigns those ticket to me and if needed, I can distribute them further.

I would now like Asana to send a feedback to the person who opened the ticket, when I close it. This only works if the sender is a `follower` on Asana. To add followers, their E-Mail has to be in the `CC` of the email opening the ticket.

Long story short: I would like to have an email forwarding (on Gmail, if it's not possible we could use an external service as well, but I would prefer to have it on Gmail), that adds the sender of the email as a `CC`

Example
`foo@company.com` sends an email to `ticket@company.com`. Gmail then forwards that email to `x@mail.asana.com` with `foo@company.com` as CC.

Is that possible? If yes, how?